# What can I use to hang a frameless mirror?

Tags: walls, mirror, hanging

I'm looking to hang a mirror on the wall on my bathroom. It weighs about 20 or so lbs. There are no built in hooks on the back of the mirror? What should I use to hang this thing?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

At Home Depot (or Lowes) you should be able to find these [Spring Loaded Mirror Mounting Clips](http://www.homedepot.com/buy/bath-bath-mirrors-mirror-framing-kits/erias-home-decor-astoria-spring-loaded-mirror-clips-4-pack-193546.html) made specially for hanging a mirror.  They are no where near as big as a j channel and the top two have a small spring inside of them so they kind of grasp the mirror (and snugly fit on the glass).

You put the two without the springs in the bottom and the mirror just sits in them.  Two more (with the springs) added to the top prevent the mirror from falling forward.  Of course it would be best if you can get them into a beam in your wall.  And you will barely notice the clips on the mirror once it is in place.

[image: Mirror mounting clips]

Comment: There are non-spring loaded clips as well. Generally they're just tiny clear plastic L-brackets with a screw hole in them. They're probably not very strong, so you'd want to use a lot of them. There are more durable options, like this stuff...

Answer (score 6):

[Liquid Nails Mirror Adhesive](http://www.liquidnails.com/products/product.jsp?productId=39), but it does say you need to use a mechanical support as well, such as a shelf angle or "J" channel.

Another option is [Heavy Duty Construction Adhesive](http://www.liquidnails.com/products/product.jsp?productId=36) which will hold about anything.
In our new house, we installed large, frameless mirrors in each bathroom using this and it worked great.

## UPDATE

As Alex pointed out in the comments, the site for Heavy Duty Construction Adhesive does not recommend using it for mirrors. They do have two other products that are specifically for mirrors, [Mirror Adhesive (LN-930)](http://www.liquidnails.com/products/product.jsp?productId=39) and [Mirror Adhesive (LOW-VOC) (LN-730)](http://www.liquidnails.com/products/product.jsp?productId=83)

Comment: +1 for construction adhesive.  I have seen this done many times, a pain to remove if the need ever arises but should hold the mirror for a long time.

Comment: Ouch! A downvote? How can you not like Liquid Nails?

Comment: The website for the Heavy Duty Construction Adhesive specifically says it is not recommended for mirrors. I wonder what's up with that?

Comment: @Alex Hmmm...good point. It's been a year since we did it and now I'm not sure if that is the actual product we used or not. They do have a couple of products that are specifically for mirrors. I'll update my answer to include those links.

Answer (score 0):

It didn't come with anything? The one 'frameless' mirror that I have is in the dining room, and it's probably 30 lbs, but it has a wooden frame behind it and a set of small metal clips that go over the edge onto the front of the mirror and then screw into the wooden frame. It really doesn't change the look, but it supports the whole thing very nicely.

I'd try to do something similar with another frameless mirror.

Comment: It didn't come with anything! I bought it from home depot and forgot to ask them what I should use to hang it!