# What's the right name of the things that mount a frameless mirror to the wall through the mirror?

Tags: mirror

I feel silly asking this question but I don't know the term for the little things that hold a frameless mirror to the wall through holes in the mirror. They're often little plastic stars or metal washers.

I'm asking because I want to search for nice looking ones online, instead of the crappy plastic ones that are so easy to find at hardware stores.

*(And if anyone happens to know of a good site to find some iron rustic looking ones - our bathroom has lighting by Hubbardton Forge - I'd appreciate any links as well.)*

**UPDATE:** just a bit of clarification - I'm asking about the actual decorative parts that cover up the screw that secures the mirror. In my particular case the mirror is very large and was glued to the wall by my contractor. The mirror has four holes in it for additional security I guess, and he put in a kind of ugly screw/washer combo.

Because the mirror is glued to the wall there's no space behind it for a standoff, and because the holes are in the mirror, clips are not what I need. I guess what I'm looking for is just the "top" part of a standoff - the nice looking bolt head and washer part.

I've seen the word "rosette" used online but it almost always refers to an ugly plastic star that you see in cheap motels. Looking for something much nicer, a keyword or phrase I can plug into Google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This turned up a few sources --> [Googling "Mirror Screw Covers"](http://www.lmgtfy.com/?q=mirror+screw+covers)

And at least one place calls these "grommets with covers" --> [CRL Mirror Grommets](http://www.dkhardware.com/product-7268-mg40-mirror-grommets-with-chrome-covers.html)

Comment: "Decorative screw cover" turns up the best results but "grommets covers" led me there. Close enough.

Answer (score 7):

What you're looking for is called a "stand-off". From [mirrorsupports.net](http://www.mirrorsupports.net/Products/3-Away-from-wall/away-from-the-wall-options.html):

> For simple, standoffs, without the need to drill holes in the mirror, choose from the following framepegs or edgegrips. For large heavy mirrors and large offsets - drill holes in the mirror and use our standoff sytems.

[image]

[image]

Comment: See my update. The mirror is glued to the wall so a standoff isn't something I can use.

Answer (score 3):

[Mirror mounting clips](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/564/what-can-i-use-to-hang-a-frameless-mirror/570#570) (links to an answer to a similar question)

[image: mirror mounting clips]

Comment: Clips aren't what I need. There are already holes in the mirror that I need to use, not an edge mounting. I updated the question.

Answer (score 2):

The decorative "washers" that cover the holes in the mirror are called rosettes

Answer (score 1):

I just called them 'hole plugs' and found a few options. You can include a material to find better options "hole plugs metal" "hole plugs plastic"

http://www.heyco.com/products/thumb_05.html

http://www.stockcap.com/hole-plug.html