# How to install a large mirror on drywall?

Tags: mirror

I need to reattach(*) a large, flat, frameless mirror (about 8'x6') to drywall, and a few long/thin beveled mirror pieces around it as a "frame".

Two questions:

1. What adhesive should I use? Epoxy glue? Liquid Nail?
2. How to hold the mirrors in place while the glue is setting? (If the glue sets in a short time, say 10 minutes, then I guess I can simply lean on it while playing Angry Birds.)

---

* If you're curious why I said "re"attach, it's because the mirrors were there originally, and I removed them to open a small doorway on the wall. I was able to simply ply the mirrors off.

Comment: Duplicate of http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/564/what-can-i-use-to-hang-a-frameless-mirror ?

Comment: @Alex Feinman: I don't think it's a dup. That question is about a much smaller mirror to hang on the wall, and the accepted answer (clips) definitely doesn't work here. Another answer over there is Liquid Nails, but all require additional support.

Comment: Then maybe additional support is required. Otherwise you are effectively gluing to paper, and that's not going to have the strength you need. I would follow the second answer listed in that question in your case.

Comment: Be careful, sometimes angry birds fly into mirrors and hurt themselves!

Comment: If you can, test the glue on an inconspicuous part of the mirror.  The prior home owners put up a wall of 1'x1' mirrored tiles and the glue had stained through the back of most of them.  And pulling them off caused significant damage to the drywall.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Mirror Adhesive](http://www.rona.ca/shop/~adhesive-mirror-adhesive-mulco-414642_mulco_paint_shop) ("*mirror mastic*") exists:

[image]

As for how to hold it up; rest it on something:

- the top of the backsplash
- rest it on a strip of wood fastened to the wall

and use mirror clips while it sets.